# When trying to authorize using OAuth endpoint i'm getting Invalid consent request [Snowflake]

Tags: authentication, oauth, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I created a security integration as below

```
create security integration testSecurityInt
  type = oauth
  enabled = true
  oauth_client = custom
  oauth_client_type = 'confidential'
  oauth_redirect_uri = 'https://xxxx-1.snowflakecomputing.com'
  oauth_issue_refresh_tokens = true
  oauth_refresh_token_validity = 7776000
```

The authorize endpoint is :

```
https://xxxx.snowflakecomputing.com/oauth/authorize
```

I altered user test01 to add delegation

```
ALTER USER TEST01 ADD DELEGATED AUTHORIZATION
    OF ROLE TEST
    TO SECURITY INTEGRATION testSecurityInt;
```

Next I'm trying to authorize using web browser

```
https://xxxx.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxxx=&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://xxxx.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com
```

After giving proper TEST01 credentials its giving the error invalid consent request

Answer (score 2):

Downloaded postman and went to Authorization section
from the drop-down choose OAuth 2.0 and gave all the required inputs 
used Client Authentication as Basic Auth header and I generated token successfully

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you are passing the client id and redirect URI parameters in the URL encoded form?

For example, If your authorization endpoint is https://.snowflakecomputing.com/oauth/authorize.
Then you need to add the query parameters like client_id,response_type,redirect_uri to the above authorization endpoint. So your URL should look like below-

https://.snowflakecomputing.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=&response_type=code&redirect_uri=
 
You can refer the below document for more details.
 
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/oauth-custom.html#authorization-endpoint

Comment: I did that after that it redirects to the page where i give TEST01 username and password, i even pasted the authorize link with client_id response_type and redirect_uri